# error received when restoring state to view in navigation controller in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller, state-restoration

When my app starts up I receive the following error:

> Exception occurred restoring state Could not find a navigation
>   controller for segue 'mySegue'. Push segues can only be used when the
>   source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController

This segue is connected to a view inside of a navigation controller.  My app navigation looks like the following:

`UITabBarController` > with a `UiNavigationController` child > with a `UIViewController` embed in the nav controller > another view controller once a user clicks the first view controller and is transitioned via 'mySegue' segue.

My nav controller is a standard nav controller which looks like this in the interface:

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

The implementation only has the override methods and the two restoration methods:

```
- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
```

Why am i receiving this error if my UIViewController is in a nav controller?

Comment: What view in 1st view controller performs the segue? Can you log segue's source/destinationViewController in `prepareForSegue:sender: method`?

Comment: Show us overridden implementation and try to run the app without them

Comment: i just ran the app without attach the overrides and i don't receive the error any longer.  It maybe that I don't reach the case in which the error happens previously though.  I will watch that event and report back.